# I added the [Authorize] attribute to the HomeController, got an exception "Unable to set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, requirejs

I am trying to use RequireJS with my ASP.NET MVC 5 application.  With a "default" (e.g. simple File->New Project) web MVC application, you are given a lot of boilerplate code, some being for user login to the application.  So, I took that default application and started to build it up, with the intent to use RequireJS to make it modular, when I ran into my first hurdle.  I added the [Authorize] attribute to the HomeController just to start working with the authorization stuff.  The idea being to force a user to login to the application before using any part of the application.

As soon as I added the [Authorize] attribute to the HomeController, I am faced with an exception "Unable to set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined or null reference".  I know it has to to with the following section in the Login.cshtml file:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Reading through all of the RequireJS documentation and googling, I am pretty sure it has to do with jquery validation, so I have the following config setup:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-2.1.1",
        "jquery.validate": "jquery.validate",
        "jquery.validate.unobtrusive": "jquery.validate.unobtrusive"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.validate": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.validate.unobtrusive": ["jquery", "jquery.validate"]
    }
});

require(["app/app"], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.init();
});
```

Just using this config does not work.  I can't seem to get rid of the exception.  I am clearly not understanding how to set this up.  I probably need to change how the Login.cshtml page is loading jquery validation, but I am confused.

Has anyone else been able to successfully integrate RequireJS into their ASP.NET MVC application and get the authentication stuff to work?

By the way, I do know there is the RequireJS.NET project available, but I really want to understand how to do this (and what I am obviously missing with my current problem) before just grabbing another library that may hide the details from me.

Comment: Null Reference Exceptions are always caused by the same thing: you tried to dereference an empty object variable.  The remedy is always the same: find the empty object variable, and make sure it contains an actual object instance before dereferencing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I fully understand what is causing the exception, what I don't fully understand is how RequireJS wires up the dependencies for jquery validation....which is why I was looking for some guidance from someone who may have figured this out already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured this out.  I had to tell RequireJS what the dependencies are for the login page...one of those requirements being jquery.validate.  It looks something like this:

```
/*global console, require*/
require(["jquery", "jquery.validate"], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(function () {
    });
});
```

Once I did that, the exception went away.